# Rails Heroku pg_ext.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app with Heroku. The app works fine in a local environment, and `git push heroku master` works fine, but an application error page is displayed when I try to view the deployed app. I'm getting similar errors from the logs and whenever I try to run a `heroku run rake db:migrate` command:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': libruby.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
```

Windows 10 Bash with Ubuntu

Ruby 2.3.4p301

Rails 5.0.3

PostgreSQL 9.3.16

pg Gem 0.21.0

I've checked multiple posts that had the same error, but none of them helped.

Comment: Can You try these commands: rvm gemset empty  -----then--------- gem install bundler -----then---------  bundle install

Comment: i tried those. no luck.

Comment: Try downgrading Ruby to 2.3.3 . According to this issue https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3645 that might be a solution

Comment: That fixed the error above, but now I get 'Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.3.' The weird thing is that the ruby version in my local machine and in Heroku are both 2.3.3. I don't even have 2.3.1 installed locally.

Comment: Do You have both RVM installed and a system Ruby installed ? I have seen that same error when people install both. Usually only RVM îs needed

Comment: Please try uninstall system Ruby. You can check if You have by following these steps. First make RVM use system Ruby with 'rvm use system' . And then execute 'ruby -v'. If that prints a Ruby version...You can check where îs installed with command 'which ruby' and try to uninstall it. Unfortunately i never used Ruby on Windows only on Linux systems so i am afraid i can not help You with the uninstall

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i fixed the problem by remaking the bin folder in my project

Comment: Cool. Glad to help and thanks for replying. It's good to know what was the problem :)